# Take Pipeline input write directly to pipeline output

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I want to execute / chain several PowerShell cmdlets.   Initial input from a  CSV.   There may be more values in the CSV than the initial command needs but they may be needed further down the chain.  Like this:

```
 CSV
 email, fname, lname, clubNo, permission
 A@email.com, John, Smith, 12, R
 B@email.com, Jean, Smith, 12, R
 C@email.com, Jack, Smith, 12, R
```

Then chain

```
 import-csv file.txt | new-user -env Dev | set-role | export-csv result.txt
```

new-user only needs email, env
set-role needs email, clubNo, env, and perm

I thought my new-user cmdlet should look something like this but its not working:

```
function global:new-user {
param(  
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, mandatory = $true)][validateset('DEV', 'QA', 'PT', 'PLT', 'SIT', 'APIS', 'PD', 'Sandbox')][STRING]$env,
    [Parameter( mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)][ValidateScript({ValidateEmail($_)})][String]$Email,
    [String]$userKey="xyz",
    [String]$secret="abc"
) 

Begin {
    $dc = "domain.com"
    $auth = "env=$env&userkey=$userKey&secret=$secret"
    $record = New-Object psobject
    $record | add-member env $env
}

process {
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod "https://accounts.$dc/accounts.search?$auth" -Method Post -Body @{"query" = "select UID FROM accounts where profile.email contains '$Email'"}
    If (-not $result.errorCode ) {
        $record | Add-Member uid $result.uid
    }
    $record | Add-Member ErrorCode $result.errorCode -Force
}

end {
    Write-Output $rescord
}
```

}

But I'm only seeing one record on the outbound pipeline

Comment: I think you just need this:  import-csv file.txt | foreach { do what you need to do } | export-csv result.txt

Comment: I modified my original to more reflect what I'm actually reflect what my code looks like

Answer (score 1):

Begin/End block are invoked once during the cmdlet execution, so you just create a $record object in the beginning, overwrite it's properties in process block and send it down the pipe once at the end. You also do not keep other properties from the csv file. I guess you just need to do everything in the process block, and instead of creating new object, just keep using input object ($_)

```
begin {
   $dc = "domain.com"
   $auth = "env=$env&userkey=$userKey&secret=$secret"
}
process {

    $_ | add-member env $env
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod "https://accounts.$dc/accounts.search?$auth" -Method Post -Body @{"query" = "select UID FROM accounts where profile.email contains '$Email'"}
    If (-not $result.errorCode ) {
        $_ | Add-Member uid $result.uid
    }
    $_ | Add-Member ErrorCode $result.errorCode -Force
    Write-Output $_
}
end {}
```